# How do I unit test the scheduled logics?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, fluentscheduler

This question is regarding unit testing the scheduled methods.

I am using `FluentScheduler` to achieve the scheduled job execution.

Here is my `Execute` method

```
public void Execute()
{
   var provisioningRepo = _containerFactory.GetInstance<IProvisioningRepo>();
   var discounts = provisioningRepo.GetDiscounts();
   if (discounts.Count == 0)
     return;

   foreach (var discount in discounts)
   {
       //doing some logics
   }    
}
```

Here is my `app.config' entry for scheduler.

```
      <add key="myMinitueSchedule" value="60" />
```

Question 1: How do I test method executed at right time? that is every 60 seconds?

Question 2: Logic inside execute need to be tested independent to scheduler?

Comment: Have you looked at FluentScheduler's own [unit tests](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler/tree/master/UnitTests/ScheduleTests)?

Comment: No. Seems like good idea to start with. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to your question 2:
The logic inside the method `Execute()` can be tested as follows:
Just outsorce the "logic operations" on your list `discounts`. Then you are able to unit test the method `MakeLogicThingsWithDiscount` logic separately:

```
public void Execute()
{
   var provisioningRepo = _containerFactory.GetInstance<IProvisioningRepo>();
   var discounts = provisioningRepo.GetDiscounts();
   if (discounts.Count == 0)
     return;
   discounts = MakeLogicThingsWithDiscount(discounts);
}

private IEnumerable<Discount> MakeLogicThingsWithDiscount(IEnumerable<Discount> discounts)
{
   //make logic things here
}
```

Comment: How do I create mock for classes which has multiple inheritance?

Comment: I don't understand your question completely. The condition for mocking is that the class is able for instantiation. Therefor you have to implement a constructor. Multiple inheritance doesn't prohibit the instantiation of a class. So whats your problem exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473303/how-do-i-unit-test-the-method-which-has-dependency-on-base-classes

Comment: I can't comment your other post because of reputation. Please write the code of the base class in your post too.

Comment: Like Nkosi said: Show your current version of UnitTest too, so that the context is more understandable.

Comment: updated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473303/how-do-i-unit-test-the-method-which-has-dependency-on-base-classes