# How do I unit test the method which has dependency on base classes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a below class, which having base class and I am trying to write unit test.

```
public class CarService : ServiceBase, IProvisioningService
{
    private IAuditRepository _repository;
    public CarService(IHostingFactory hostingFactory) : base(name, hostingFactory)
    {         

    }

    public override void DoWork()
    {
        if (_repository == null)
          {
             //its calling the base method.
            _repository = CurrentContext.ContainerFactory.GetInstance<IAuditRepository>();                  
        try
        {
            _repository.Insert("something");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }       
  }
}
```

CurrentContext.ContainerFactory is part of base class. `CurrentContext.ContainerFactory` throws null exception. How do I create Mock for these classes?

Is interface is must for unit testing?

**Updated with base class**

```
public abstract class ServiceBase : IServiceBase
{
    public HostingContext CurrentContext { get; }
    public string ServiceName { get; }

    protected ServiceBase(string serviceName, IHostingFactory hostingFactory)
    {
        ServiceName = serviceName;

        _stopSignal = false;
        CurrentContext = hostingFactory.CreateContext(serviceName);
        Logger = CurrentContext.LoggerInstance;
    }

}
```

**HostingContext class**

```
   public class HostingContext
   {
        public HostingContext(
        Func<string, ILogger> loggerFactory,
        string serviceName, 
        string connString): this(loggerFactory(contextName),serviceName, connString, new ContainerFactory())
    {}
 }
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
       MockRepository repository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
       var containerFactoryMock = repository.Create<IContainerFactory>();
       var auditRepositoryMock = repository.Create<IAuditRepository>();
       var hostingFactoryMock = repository.Create<IHostingFactory>();
                   var hostingContextMock = new HostingContext("Sample", "ConnString",containerFactoryMock.Object);


        hostingFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.CurrentContext(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(hostingContextMock);
        CarService carService = new CarService(hostingFactoryMock.Object);

        carService.Work();
```

Comment: Then it looks like you just need to provide the class under test with the necessary dependencies to allow the test to be exercised to completion. either provide a mocked `IHostingFactory` with desired behavior or provide a stub instance if possible.

Comment: updated with the test. I feel code is messy. basically I do not want to fix exact code, I want to understand the best practice and right way to mock. so that I can write clean code from scratch.

Comment: Right so far so good. You did not setup the container factor's behavior so when you call `.GetInstance<IAuditRepository>()` it will return null. hence your error.

Comment: Can u show me the code change ?

Comment: check provided example.

Comment: Have you considered not testing this class ? I mean there is no business logic to test here: `if (_repository == null)` is only initialization logic (which by the way could be avoided with better design) then there is only a call to `_repository.Insert("something");` which is wrapped in a try/catch block. Eventually testing the repository can be useful, as long as it contains a bit of business logic (but I doubt).

Comment: When you say that "you feel the code is messy", it's a sign not to ignore that this code is not a good candidate in an unit test suite. Requiring the use of mocks is another sign that you shouldn't unit test something. See [this article](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/06/15/pragmatic-unit-testing/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You did not setup the container factory's behavior so when you call `.GetInstance<IAuditRepository>()` it will return *null*, hence your error.

Provide the class under test with the necessary dependencies to allow the test to be exercised to completion.

```
//Arrange
var repository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
var containerFactoryMock = repository.Create<IContainerFactory>();
var auditRepositoryMock = repository.Create<IAuditRepository>();
var hostingFactoryMock = repository.Create<IHostingFactory>();
var loggerMock = repository.Create<ILogger>();

var hostingContextMock = new HostingContext(loggerMock, "Sample", "ConnString",containerFactoryMock.Object);

hostingFactoryMock
    .Setup(_ => _.CreateContext(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(hostingContextMock);

containerFactoryMock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetInstance<IAuditRepository>())
    .Returns(auditRepositoryMock);

CarService carService = new CarService(hostingFactoryMock.Object);

//Act
carService.Work();

//Assert
auditRepositoryMock.Verify(_ => _.Insert(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
```

Comment: My HostingContext has dependency on Func<string, ILogger> loggerFactory. How do I create mock of it?